# How to sort by sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have the following SQL Query:

- **Points**: id, special, user, points, book, type, date.
- **Videos**: id, title, points, src, photo, token, special
- **Book**: id, title, image, end_date, token, token_id, author. description

Each video has a *special* id. The points will tell you which video you watched based on the *special* matching on **points** and **videos**

Each book has a *token*. The video is told which video to go on based on the *token*.

--

What I want to do? I want to have a page that displays the point value a a user has used.

[image]

I have tried to do this code:

```
$one = $db->query("SELECT * FROM points WHERE user='$user' GROUP BY book");

while($fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_array($one)) {
$special = $fetch_data["special"]; 
$points = $fetch_data["points"]; 
$type = $fetch_data["type"]; 
$date = $fetch_data["date"]; 

  // FIND BOOK
$two = $db->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE special='$special'"); 

while($fetch_data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($two)) {
 $title = $fetch_data2["title"]; 

 // At this point echo output
}

}
```

Comment: simple user inner join

Comment: @JYoThI I'm a beginner, would you mind giving an example :)

Comment: "SELECT p.*,v.* FROM points as p inner join videos as v on v.special =p.special WHERE p.user='".$user."' group by p.books"

Answer (score 2):

Use inner join to fetch the data from videos and points and loop through the result

```
$query = $db->query("Select a.*,b.* from points a inner join videos b on a.special = b.special where a.user = '$user'")

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query){
//echo the output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `INNER JOIN` no need multiple query

```
"SELECT p.*,v.* FROM points as p 
 inner join videos as v 
 on v.special =p.special 
 WHERE p.user='".$user."' 
 group by p.books"
```